# JoinAcross question with combined keys

Tags: dataset, associations

I would like to join associations in the following way. Say I have a dataset d1:

```
keys1 = {"first", "last", "age"};
first = {"Mike", "Carl", "Tina"};
last = {"Shulz", "Miller", "Ruben"};
age = {28, 35, 34};
```

then

```
d1 = Dataset[
  AssociationThread[keys1, #] & /@ ({first, last, age}\[Transpose])]
```

and a second dataset

```
names = d1[All, {"first", "last"}][All, #first ~~ " " ~~ #last &] // 
  Normal
(*{"Mike Shulz", "Carl Miller", "Tina Ruben"} *)
```

and

```
income = {30000, 23000, 40000}
```

so the dataset d2 is

```
d2 = Dataset[
  AssociationThread[{"fullname", "income"}, #] & /@ ({names, 
      income}\[Transpose])]
```

Then I would like to combine (join) these datasets on the full name of a person, which is present in the second dataset but not in the first. Something like

```
JoinAcross[Normal@d1, 
 Normal@d2, (Key["first"] ~~ Key["last"]) -> Key["fullname"]]
```

(clearly) does not work. Is there an easy way to achieve the desired result (without modifying the first dataset and append a full name on it)?

Edit:

Besides the question is answered by a good workaround another questions arises: "Why the coloring"? I tried the solution from WReach - works fine, but I get parts of the answer colored and do not know why... Can someone help (again)?... Sorry, I just saw it: missing braces {}....

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, `JoinAcross` does not presently (V11.1) support any form of computed key specification.  We have no choice but to adjust the first dataset to include the full name.

We do not necessarily have to go so far as to destructively alter `d1` -- we can add the computed column in an inline query:

```
JoinAcross[
  d1[All, <| "fullname"-> #first~~" "~~#last, # |> &] // Normal
, d2 // Normal
, Key["fullname"] -> Key["fullname"]
] // Dataset
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

---

As an aside, in later versions of Mathematica we can *usually* omit the applications of `Normal`, `Key` and `Dataset`:

```
JoinAcross[
  d1[All, <| "fullname"-> #first~~" "~~#last, # |> &]
, d2
, "fullname" -> "fullname"
]
```

... but be prepared to add them back in since `JoinAcross` has been very finicky across releases (especially when applied to datasets).

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer, so I´m going to take this as a (quite good) workaround

Answer (score 1):

In:

```
keys1 = {"first", "last", "age"};
first = {"Mike", "Carl", "Tina"};
last = {"Shulz", "Miller", "Ruben"};
age = {28, 35, 34};
d1 = Dataset[AssociationThread[keys1, #] & /@ ({first, last, age}\[Transpose])]

fullname[person_] := "fullname" -> person["first"] <> " " <> person["last"]
addFullname[person_] := Prepend[person, fullname@person]
addFullnames[persons_] := persons // Normal // Map[addFullname] // Dataset
addFullnames@d1
```

Out:
[image]